# Flutter does not work custom enum for swtich statement

Tags: flutter, dart, enums, switch-statement

```
abstract class Enum<T> {
  final T value;

  const Enum(this.value);
}


class FlightScheduleStatus<int> extends Enum<int> {
  const FlightScheduleStatus(int val) : super(val);
  static const None = const FlightScheduleStatus(0);
  static const OnTime = const FlightScheduleStatus(1);
  static const Delayed = const FlightScheduleStatus(2);
}


Widget getFlightStates(LiveStatus liveStatus) {
switch (liveStatus.flightScheduleStatus) {
      case FlightScheduleStatus.Delayed:
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Delayed'),
            SizedBox(
              width: 3,
            ),
            Chip(
              label: Text('${liveStatus.delayedTime}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        );
        break;
      case FlightScheduleStatus.OnTime:
        return Text('On Time');
        break;
      case FlightScheduleStatus.None:
        return Text('N/A');
        break;
    }
}
```

here I have created custom enum with custom class. but when we use switch statement does not go through any of the case here. please help me on this issue. I want to work this code as it is if it is a enum class.

even I use `liveStatus.flightScheduleStatus.value` its not working.

Comment: can you add liveStatus.flightScheduleStatus and liveStatus.flightScheduleStatus.value ?

Comment: I created a sample based on your code and its working fine. Have a look at [this dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/25b511e8c606a34211330f5dc4a65f96).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is your `FlightScheduleStatus` class actually allow you to create multiple object instances with the same internal value. Since you have a public constructor for `FlightScheduleStatus` I am guessing you are using that elsewhere in you code to convert a `int` into a `FlightScheduleStatus`. If that is the case, you really need to use a factory constructor like the following example:

```
abstract class Enum<T> {
  final T value;

  const Enum(this.value);
}

class FlightScheduleStatus extends Enum<int> {
  const FlightScheduleStatus._(int val) : super(val);

  factory FlightScheduleStatus(int val) {
    if (val == None.value) {
      return None;
    } else if (val == OnTime.value) {
      return OnTime;
    } else if (val == Delayed.value) {
      return Delayed;
    }
    throw Exception('$val is not a valid value for FlightScheduleStatus.');
  }

  static const None = const FlightScheduleStatus._(0);
  static const OnTime = const FlightScheduleStatus._(1);
  static const Delayed = const FlightScheduleStatus._(2);
}

void main() {
  var test = FlightScheduleStatus(0);

  switch (test) {
    case FlightScheduleStatus.None:
      print('None'); // <-- this is the one executed
      break;
    case FlightScheduleStatus.OnTime:
      print('OnTime');
      break;
    case FlightScheduleStatus.Delayed:
      print('Delayed');
      break;
  }
}
```

In the example I have made the normal constructor for `FlightScheduleStatus` private so it is only used by `FlightScheduleStatus` itself. The factory contructor allow us to return objects which have already be created instead of creating new objects.